# What are rules for whether or not using ^ to point to value?

Tags: delphi

Below is a simple example of using pointer in delphi.

```
Type

TRecord1 = Record
field1 : String;

end; 

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   Rec : TRecord1;
   Ptr: ^TRecord1;

begin
   Rec.field1:= 'field1';
   Ptr := @Rec;
   memo1.Lines.Add (Ptr^.field1); 
   memo1.Lines.Add (Ptr.field1); // it also works.

 end;
```

In such case, Ptr^ and Ptr both work. It seems delphi is to allow user more flexibility in pointing to the value. But just by reading the two lines, they are syntactically different and may mean differently. In such case both work. But my question is:

1. how can a user know in other situations where ^ can or can not be
   omitted or, where with ^ or without ^ means the same or differently?
2. What are those situations ? Examples will be appreciated.
3. Why? (Optional)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: When `ptr` is a pointer type (includig implicit pointers), dereferencing can be omitted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> how can a user know in other situations where ^ can or can not be omitted or, where with ^ or without ^ means the same or differently?
>
> What are those situations ? Examples will be appreciated.

A plain `Pointer` doesn't have any fields or properties, so ignoring Delphi's smarts, the `Pointer.Field` syntax doesn't make sense. Because of that there can't be a conflict between `Pointer^.Field` and `Pointer.Field`, simply because the plain `.` syntax is meaningless if you don't dereference the pointer.

If the type pointed to by the pointer doesn't have any fields you have to use the `^` syntax. That is, when the pointer is a pointer to a basic type, or is an untyped pointer.

> Why? (Optional)

Class instance references (what most people would call "objects") are also pointers in Delphi, I assume the syntax was introduced to make working with Pointers less verbose and more like using classes. It's also harmless, because as mentioned above, the compiler can't get it wrong.

I personally prefer the `^.` syntax, because it makes it clear I'm working with a pointer and not a record or class.

Comment: "Classes are also pointers in Delphi" - shouldn't this be "Object references are also pointers in Delphi"?

Comment: @mjn It should better be "Classes instances are also pointer in Delphi", since "Object reference" could refer to the `object` keyword, shouldn't it? Whatever, we all got the point. ;)

Comment: @A.Bouchez since object is a value type object reference can mean only one this. I personally prefer the use of object in discussions to mean an instance of a class. It's less wordy.

Comment: "Class instances are also pointers in Delphi" sounds incorrect to me too :)

Comment: +1 "I personally prefer the ^. syntax, because it makes it clear.." me too.

Answer (score 3):

The only difference is that

```
Ptr1 := Ptr2
```

**is not equal to**

```
Ptr1^ := Ptr2^
```

The first line will make Ptr1 and Ptr2 to point to the same memory area, the second will assign the value pointed to by Ptr2 to the "variable" pointed to by Ptr1.

For this reason I believe allowing the Ptr.Field value syntax should be a bug, because even if no ambiguity may arise from the compiler side, it introduces a lazy way of writing code, that could backfire in situations like those above.

Answer (score 2):

ptr.property is never valid and distinctly different from ptr^.property so Delphi allows you to leave out the ^. if ptr is not typed (or is a basic datatype) then ^ is always required.

Comment: ptr.property is a valid syntax, even if ptr^.property is more correct.

Comment: @A.Bouchez: I think you misunderstood the answer here. He made the same point as Cosmin and said that `ptr.property` would never make sense and so Delphi can do nothing wrong (+1 to make up for the downvote)

Comment: @Smasher, @A.Bouchez, I also think the wording of Gordy's answer is truly confusing: If you understand the underlying issue you might guess what the meaning is, but otherwise the answer is misleading. A.Bouchez is perfectly correct, `ptr.property` *is* valid syntax, and without further explanation that makes half the answer incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple. If the use of ptr.field is UNambiguous, i.e. if it can't have any other meaning than ptr^.field, the ^ can be omitted.

But only then. In cases where omitting the ^ creates an ambiguous construct (i.e. where it could have different meanings), it can't be omitted.